# Why get(index) slow more than remove(index) of LinkedList in Java

Tags: java

I have a LinkedList with 100000 items of String.When i do an operation with index such as get,remove,add, it seems same mechanism. 
First it browse the list to access Node[index], then does a another manipulation,
with "get" it only references to item of Node, whereas even the "remove" does more.
But why is the "get" operation take alot more time than the "remove" operation

```
for(int index=99999;index>=0;index--){
    links.get(index);
}
```

get time in nanoseconds: 15083052805

```
for(int index=99999;index>=0;index--){
    links.remove(index);
}
```

del time in nanoseconds: 2310625

LinkedList's functions:

```
public E get(int index) {
    checkElementIndex(index);
    return node(index).item;
}

public E remove(int index) {
    checkElementIndex(index);
    return unlink(node(index));
}
```

Comment: did you warm up JVM properly before benchmarking ?

Comment: useful links  [correct benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java#answer-513259), [robust benchmarking](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-benchmark1/)

Comment: Also, 99999 is not big enough for a benchmark.

Comment: @ΔλЛ For an O(N*N) problem, which his get(i) loop represents, 100k elements can be quite enough.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the element at index N is very costly, since to actually get to the element the list nodes need to be traversed until the element is reached.

Now when you remove the elements in your loop, realize that youre always removing the *last* element of the list (your i corresponds exactly with list.size()-1 at all times in that loop).

The node(index) method actually optimizes the access by searching from the front/back, depending on if index is closer to 0 or list.size(). In your case of remove its always searching from the back and hits on the first try.

Lesson to be learned: LinkedList is *not* a suitable list type to access by random index.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not polling `System.currentTimeMillis()` (getting the current time) before entering the first loop.